# What is the CSS code for moving button on a slider for Divi Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Divi Wordpress theme to build my website. I am creating a slider and trying to customize the CTA button. But it will not move from its default center position. Could you help me with the CSS code to move its position?

Here is what I am trying to do:

[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYL7C.jpg)

Comment: It's difficult to help when you don't provide code sample (HTML and current CSS) or a link to the page so that we can help. Maybe you could do that and I can try help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Click on the three line in upper left of the module
2. Click on the three line in upper left of the slide
3. Click "Advance" tab and scroll down to find "slide button"
4. In slied button, type margin-left: 75% (play around with this number)

[Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw28Z.png)